A space opera novel about a dictatorial regime and opponents with a "secret weapon"
I read a space opera novel more than 40 years ago. Probably in a paperback but I don't remember the cover.
I do not remember much. There is a dictatorial regime in planet which has conquered some of its neighbours. There are oppositions which are ferociously repressed.
One young man finds out his father has been executed as an opponent and that they are looking for him. So he has no choice but to flee. There are many events which I have totally forgotten. At some point he hears about a planet where opponents are regrouping and that they have a very high morale, thanks to a "secret weapon" that will guarantee the victory.
He reaches this planet, and finds out that the "secret weapon" is the US Constitution.

This sounds very much like The Stars Like Dust, an early novel by Isaac Asimov, first released in 1958.
The hero of the story is Biron Farrill. He is the heir to a planet that has recently been conquered by an expanding planetary empire, appropriately named the "Tyranni". When his father is killed he has to flee, and goes to join the resistance movement. He and his companions originally think the resistance must be literally hidden in the Horsehead nebula, but it turns out actually to be "hidden in plain sight" (as is the Director of the resistance).
From the Wikipedia summary:

It is further revealed that the Director, who possesses a collection
of ancient documents, has searched for and has found a document that
will help a future empire, likely Trantor, govern the galaxy. The
document is eventually revealed to be the United States Constitution...

...by the Director reciting the words he had committed to memory:

“‘We the people of the United States, in order to form a more perfect
Union,  establish  justice,  insure  domestic  tranquillity, provide
for the common defense, promote the general welfare, and secure the
blessings of liberty to ourselves and our posterity, do ordain  and
establish  this  Constitution  for  the  United  States of America
...’

The full novel is available from the Internet Archive.

Trantor, sounds familiar!
